# I can't shut down java.exe permanently in windows vista

Tags: windows-vista, java

java.exe is always running even though I'm not running any java programs. It uses a lot of memory and 50% CPU all the time. Every time i close it in taskmanager, it restarts again.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you are not running anything which needs Java? Like some app in your web browser? Do a clean restart and see if java.exe launches automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Download and install [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) it should be able to tell you what is starting `java.exe`
When you know what is starting it you can (if you want) disable the offending applications autostart using something like [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)

If this does not work you may have a [malware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware) infection. To get rid of that follow the advice found in this question: [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

If it still does not work ask a new question listing the things you have tried so far.